# Adhoc saiku queries

Tags: mondrian, saiku

With no luck finding on net, I am bound to ask this here. How does Saiku makes queries to mondrian? If some one can kindly point to the exact path of query generation to result display it will be just perfect.

Thanking in advance =)

Comment: Use Chrome Developer Tools, and you can see the network traffic between the Saiku client and Jersey backend.

Answer (score 0):

Till i know saiku will not make any query directly, you have to create your mdx query into schema workbench and after creating cube in schema workbench you have to publish those cubes in bi server.(schema workbench is modified version of mondrian,you can read more regarding the same)

so you are able to visualize it in bi server..

and if you want to display that result into saiku only then add saiku pluggin into bi server so that you can analyze your output in saiku also.